# Having problems with EE mail library code

Tags: ee

I'm new to Expression Engine, I'm hoping someone can help me out with an issue? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.
What I'm trying to do is send an email.

My template code looks like this:

```
{embed="main/header1"}
<meta name="Description" content="whatever">
<meta name="Keywords" content="stuff">
{embed="main/header2"}
{embed="main/navbar"}

{exp:channel:entries channel="subscription" limit="1"}
<div id="content2">
<div id="Image">
    <img src="{page_image}" alt="alt text" /></div>
<div id="Content">
    <?php
    echo $_GET['email_address'];
    ?>

$email_msg = "email address: $email_val";
$email_to = "email@address.com"

ee()->load->library('email');
ee()->load->helper('text');

ee()->email->wordwrap = true;
ee()->email->mailtype = 'text';
ee()->email->from("Expression Engine");
ee()->email->to($email_to);

ee()->email->subject(Test);
ee()->email->message(entities_to_ascii($email_msg));
ee()->email->Send();
</div>
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
{embed="main/footer"}
```

All of the EE library code is outputting to the screen as text, rather than being executed. What am I missing? Thanks for your help. PHP is enabled.
- James.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your php code inside php tags.

```
{embed="main/header1"} 
{embed="main/header2"} 
{embed="main/navbar"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="subscription" limit="1"}
<?php
   $email_msg = "email address: $email_val"; 
   $email_to = "email@address.com" ee()->load->library('email');
   ee()->load->helper('text'); 
   ee()->email->wordwrap = true; 
   ee()->email->mailtype = 'text';
   ee()->email->from("Expression Engine"); 
   ee()->email->to($email_to); 
   ee()->email->subject(Test); 
   ee()->email->message(entities_to_ascii($email_msg)); 
   ee()->email->Send();
?>
{/exp:channel:entries} {embed="main/footer"}
```

More in the [EE documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/php.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have just closed `PHP` end tag in wrong place. You just need to put a `PHP` end tag after your `PHP Mail` code. So, try my suggested code as below. I hope it will work for you.

```
{embed="main/header1"}
<meta name="Description" content="whatever">
<meta name="Keywords" content="stuff">
{embed="main/header2"}
{embed="main/navbar"}

{exp:channel:entries channel="subscription" limit="1"}
<div id="content2">
    <div id="Image">
        <img src="{page_image}" alt="alt text" />
    </div>
    <div id="Content">
    <?php
        echo $_GET['email_address'];

        $email_msg = "email address: $email_val";
        $email_to = "email@address.com"

        ee()->load->library('email');
        ee()->load->helper('text');

        ee()->email->wordwrap = true;
        ee()->email->mailtype = 'text';
        ee()->email->from("Expression Engine");
        ee()->email->to($email_to);

        ee()->email->subject(Test);
        ee()->email->message(entities_to_ascii($email_msg));
        ee()->email->Send();
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
{embed="main/footer"}
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my issues. I'd also left out a semi-colon.